# Считать текст из таблицы текстового файла .docx с помощью C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, office-interop

Есть множество файлов .docx с некоторым текстом и таблицами.

В таблицах содержатся строки и столбцы из которых необходимо извлекать текст для того чтобы уже в программе сопоставлять эти данные с данными из таблиц полученных из других источников.

Какими средствами пользоваться для чтения? OpenXML и Interop примеров и инструкций для создания новых таблиц и добавления данных в уже готовые достаточно в интернете, но я не нашел ни одного для чтения.

С помощью OpenXML считал отдельно таблицы и строки следующим кодом:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(FileName, true))
{
    foreach (var tbl in doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<Table>())
    {
      Tables.Add(tbl);
    }

    string text = Tables[5].Elements<TableRow>().ElementAt(1).InnerText;
}
```

Однако текст отдельно ячейками не могу получить, а text получается без разделителей по формату "ТекстпервойячейкиТекствторойячейкиТексттретьейячейки.."

Есть какое-нибудь другое решение этого вопроса?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Предположим, что у вас `Tables` уже заполнено и там есть хотя бы одна таблица:

```
// Берем первую таблицу (конечно, нужно чтобы она была)
Table table = Tables[0];

// Первая строка из таблицы
TableRow row = table.Elements<TableRow>().ElementAt(0);

// Первая ячейка из строки
TableCell cell = row.Elements<TableCell>().ElementAt(0);
```

Ну а уже из ячейки берите `InnerText`. Получив ячейку, можно добраться и до более глубоких элементов, таких как параграф(абзац) `Paragraph`, прогон `Run` и диапазон текста `Text`:

```
Paragraph paragraph = cell.Elements<Paragraph>().First(); 
Run run = paragraph.Elements<Run>().First(); 
Text text = run.Elements<Text>().First();
```

---

Из приведенного вами кода, следует:

```
Tables[5].Elements<TableRow>().ElementAt(1).InnerText;
```

Обращаемся в шестую таблицу, вторую строку полученной таблицы и затем получаем весь текст строки. А нужно было еще несколько уровней пройти, чтобы попасть в ячейку `TableCell`, параграф `Paragraph` и т.д.

---

Хорошие ссылки для ознакомления:

- [Изменение текста в таблице в текстовом документе (SDK Open XML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/cc850835.aspx)
- [Работа с таблицами WordprocessingML (пакет SDK Open XML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/gg278313.aspx)
- [Класс TableCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.tablecell.aspx)
- [Свойства TableCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.tablecell_properties.aspx)
- [Как применить стиль к абзацу в текстовом документе (Open XML SDK)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/cc850838.aspx)
- [Класс Paragraph](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.paragraph.aspx)
- [Класс Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.run.aspx)
- [Класс Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.text.aspx)

Comment: У меня есть ячейки cell, в которых текст разделен переносами строки(Enter), но в результате InnerText выдает опять слипшееся выражение. Есть ли еще один "уровень ниже" или это решается по другому? У меня на одну строку приходится несколько "подстрок", в которых в первом столбце несколько разных наименований, а в остальных столбцах общие к ним параметры

Comment: @Алексей а попробуйте глубже `cell` пройти в параграф вот так: `Paragraph paragraph = cell.Elements<Paragraph>().First();
Run run = paragraph.Elements<Run>().First();
Text text = run.Elements<Text>().First();` посмотрите, что в параграфах и что в ран элементах, может быть там лежит то, что вам нужно.